# Which files from a VSTS Database Edition GDR R2 project should be excluded from source control?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-dbpro

I'm getting ready to setup a Visual Studio Database Edition GDR R2 project with source control. Which files (if any), should be excluded from source control?

Comment: Useful information guys - it's always a pain trying to decide which file to exclude from source control. Wouldn't it just be simpler, if the project structure simply contained a directory called something like 'Generated' and use this as the location of any file(s) that do not need to be (Or should not be) placed under source control. Are you listening, Microsoft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I ended up with.

```
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug
obj
[Rr]elease
*.aps
*.dbmdl
*.eto
*.ncb
*.suo
*.user
_ReSharper.*
```

Answer (score 2):

The files / directories I exclude are these:

```
/obj
/bin
/sql
/*.dbmdl
```

Answer (score 0):

I also exclude the .suo file in the solution folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also avoid the .dbschema files

Comment: they are exluded automatically when you exclude the sql\ folder